# Changing outlet object properties

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, iboutlet

I have a view controller **alertForNeedsClassification** as a property in another class, as such:

```
@interface SCAAppDelegate()
{
    HomeScreenViewController * _homeScreenViewController;
    NSInteger SCAStatus;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) PromptClassifyViewController * alertForNeedsClassification;
@end

@implementation SCAAppDelegate

@synthesize alertForNeedsClassification;
@synthesize window = _window;
```

PromptClassifyViewController's interface looks like this:

```
@interface PromptClassifyViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *headerTitle;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *message;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *notNowButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *classifyButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *backgroundImageView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *alertView;
@property NSUInteger tag;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet id<PromptClassifyViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

- (void)show;
- (void)showFromView:(UIView *)view;
- (IBAction)show:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)dismiss:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)buttonWasPressed:(id)sender;
- (void)setHeaderTitleWithText:(NSString *)text;

@end
```

I am trying to change the values of IBOutlets **message** and **headerTitle** text, like this:

```
alertForNeedsClassification = [[PromptClassifyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PromptClassifyViewController" bundle:nil];
            //[alertForNeedsClassification setDelegate:self];
            self.alertForNeedsClassification.headerTitle.text =  @"A title";


            alertForNeedsClassification.message.text = @"A message";
```

Then I show **alertForNeedsClassification** calling a **show** method (it's like a custom uialertview, but it doesn't subclass from uialertview).

Thing is, no matter how I change it, the text on alertForNeedsClassification.view is always that which is defined in the nib, ie. I can't change it programmatically.

My custom alert view is based on Jeff LaMarche's design: http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/05/custom-alert-views.html

Any ideas what might be going on?

Comment: log the value of headerTitle to see if it is null or not. If it is not, you might need a setNeedsDisplay call to update the view.

Comment: It is null, actually. (edited)

Comment: Logging it right after I set it returns null.  It doesn't even return the value it picks up from the nib.

Comment: Is the little circle before @property solid or hollow?

Comment: It's solid.  I disconnected and reconnected the outlets just to be sure.

Comment: any reason you are using weak and not retain? I don't know if weak is meaning that the garbage collector is just assuming you don't need the reference anymore. Try changing   property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *headerTitle; to property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *headerTitle;

Comment: I'm using arc.  Garbage collection doesn't apply, right? The view in question is defined as a strong reference, so it's own properties shouldn't get deallocated as long as the property pointer doesn't point to nil, using arc rules, I believe. And it wouldn't deallocate within the scope in which it's initialized either, unless I am mistaken.

Comment: Actually, I'm coming to the conclusion that I'm trying to set IBOutlet properties before they are allocated and initialized.  I put a log on viewDidLoad and it's running after I assign values to the properties.

Answer (score 0):

Please be careful when you allocate and initialize the `UIView` object, especially if you trying to mix using Nib and dynamically generating objects. The best place is within `-(void)awakeFromNib` or `-(void)viewDidLoad`

Also, make sure these methods are called. By using `-(id)initWithNibName:bundle:` only cannot make sure your view to be loaded. Try `-(void)addChildViewController` and `-(void)addSubview:` on parentViewController's view to make sure view is loaded after being initialized.

If the text had to be prepared before being loaded, assign it to separate `NSString` property within `PromptClassifyViewController` class. Since this property is independent from view being loaded, you can change it's value BEFORE view is appeared. Make sure this text is used and applied to the `headerTitle` within `-(void)show` method.

Since you allocate `PromptClassifyViewController` and access `weak` referenced `headerTitle` from `self. alertForNeedsClassification`, make sure it's not deallocated right afterward.

Usually, `weak` option is not used for IBOutlet properties. Though it is used when generating outlet connection code by dragging objects from Interface Builder. Try testing your code using `strong`.

Comment: Xcode sets the IBOutlets to weak on its own when you drag from the xib to the interface. (edit - going to try setting it to strong anyway to see if the results are different)

Comment: It used be `strong` I modify my answer after looking through your question more carefully

Comment: At this point, I'm pretty convinced that I was trying to define headerTitle and message before they were allocated and initialized.  PromptClassifyViewController's viewDidLoad runs AFTER I make the assignments, and awakeFromNib doesn't seem to run at all. 

I think the solution is to set up some NSString properties and then assign them to message.text and headerTitle.text in viewDidLoad.

Comment: It could work as you intended, if you can change `headerTitle` AFTER it was loaded and JUST BEFORE being added to a superview

Comment: hmmm I don't know if it's possible in this case.  I add the view immediately after attempting to modify its outlets.  There are no steps in between (from the point of view of the superview).

Answer (score 0):

I was assigning values to the IBOutlets before they were alloc'd/initialized.  The solution I implemented was to set the values I needed to non-IBOutlet properties (NSStrings in this case) and assign those where needed, in Prompt...Controller's viewDidLoad;

Comment: Thanks to everyone for all their help.